# How to write a text to a txt file (codeigniter)

Tags: file, function, codeigniter

After I had checked the questions here, I saw that I need write_file for text writing to a .txt file. I also looked for a tutorial or an example about it on Google but couldn't find a simple one.

Could you explain me basically about how to write something to a .txt file in Codeigniter?

As an example, a text is submitted by a user on a registration form and then the text written by the user, will be shown in users.txt.

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
$this->load->helper('file');

$data = 'Some file data';
    if ( ! write_file('./path/to/file.php', $data))
    {
            echo 'Unable to write the file';
    }
    else
    {
            echo 'File written!';
    }
```

Comment: This one also returns "Unable to write the file" as well the first example.

Comment: The folder has to be writeable.

Comment: The .txt file is in the root folder. I mean http://www.example.com/user.txt. I am not sure how to give the permission to it as writeable. I changed the user.txt' s permission to 777. Is this not enough?

Comment: Thanks a lot by the way. I create a folder and I moved the txt to that folder and then I changed its permission to 777 and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: It's enought, more is not possible. Be aware of the security, it's very unsave to make the root folder writeable. Is the path correct? It has to be relative to your index file and not to the controller.

Answer (score 5):

There is a file helper in codeIgniter called `file_helper.php` in `system/helpers` that will help you do that :

```
$this->load->helper('file');
$data = 'My Text here';

if ( !write_file('./path/to/file.txt', $data)){
     echo 'Unable to write the file';
}
```

Full documentation about `file_helper` is [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html).

Comment: After I used this codes, it says "unable to write the file." My controller is below.

<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Necmi extends CI_Controller 
{
 function index()
 {
  $this->load->helper('file');
  $data = 'My Text here';

  if ( !write_file('http://www.example.com/users.txt', $data)){
  echo 'Unable to write the file';
  }
 }
}

?>

Comment: you should use a path instead of URI (example.com/users.txt)

Comment: try for instance : `APPPATH.'/files/users.txt'`